# How to extend a static base constructor?

Tags: python, static-constructor

I'm using the Python [`bitmap` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitmap/0.0.5).

It does almost everything I need, but it don't work with hexadecimal values, which are needed by my application, so I extended it like this:

```
import bitmap
class BitMap(bitmap.BitMap):
    def tohexstring(self):
        val = self.tostring()
        st = "{0:0x}".format(int(val,2))
        return st.zfill(self.sz/4)
```

The base class has a static constructor from string:

```
bitmap.BitMap.fromstring("01010101")
```

I can make one from hexadecimal converting the hex value to bin:

```
bitmap.BitMap.fromstring(format(int("aa",16),"08b"))
```

But the returned class is the original bitmap class and not the extended one.

How can I use this constructor but still return my extended class?

Comment: Why don't you implement `fromstring` for hex in your subclass? Note that giving the same name as the superclass probably isn't ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`bitmap.BitMap.fromstring`](https://github.com/wanji/bitmap/blob/master/src/bitmap.py#L108) is a *class method*, not a *static method*, but has been implemented incorrectly by the author. The line:

```
bm = BitMap(nbits)
```

should really be

```
bm = cls(nbits)
```

in which case you could call `fromstring` on your subclass and get *an instance of the subclass*. You could fork the repo, implement this and make a pull request to have this included in the package (or just use your fork in your package). You could also raise an issue on their repo to see how they'd prefer you to proceed.

Alternatively, implement `fromstring` correctly in your own subclass and shadow the broken base class implementation.

Comment: Yep, I just realized this (about 2 seconds before you pointed it out on my answer).  It's sad that the author _correctly_ used `@classmethod` but then implemented it incorrectly ...

Comment: @mgilson it does seem odd - if they were using `pylint` or something it would have told them they weren't actually using the argument.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to - if the constructor is static, and not a classmethod, you would have to override the old constructor completely. Granted, you could call the old one in your override, copy the attributes to a new subclass instance, and return that if you really need to.